# There are something wrong about Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

1. I have build a hadoop cluster on ECS on Aliyun of Alibaba.com( it's like AWS）. The OS is Ubuntu12.04 . The version of Hadoop is 2.7.1
2. The cluster is consisted of one master and two slaves.
3. I can start it successfully. Every node can work well, and I
   can use ssh to access two slave node from master node.
4. Every node is started.
5. But when I run the wordcount program, there is something wrong. The
   error is as following:

   ```
   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.144.52.189 to localhost:38635 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
   ```
6. When I added Port 38635 in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I run the wordcount program again. The error is still existed, the only difference is the Port 38635 changed.

   ```
   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.144.52.189 to localhost:46656 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
   ```

How to fix this problem? The ports 38635 and 46656 are added in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the error occurs when run the wordcount program with a new port in the error information.